# Split dataframe column into different columns based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

i have a df

```
id   store_name   open_timings
1      abc        9 TO 1 -4 TO 11
2      bcd        8 TO 11 - 1 TO 3
3      xyz        8 TO 2
4      qwe        9 TO 2-4 TO 7
```

I want to reformat this df, such that, i create 3 more columns `start_time,end_time,closed_time`.

i.e

```
id   store_name   start_time   end_time    closed_time
1      abc         9             11           1-4
2      bcd         8              3           11-1
3      xyz         8              2           None
4      qwe         9              7           2-4
```

if possible can i convert this columns in 24 hr format,something like this.

```
id   store_name   start_time   end_time    closed_time
1      abc         9:00          11:00         13:00-16:00 
2      bcd         8:00          15:00         11:00 -13.00
3      xyz         8:00          14:00         nan
4      qwe         9:00          19:00         14:00-16:00
```

The second part is optional,

Is there any way to get this?

i have a way to split the column `open_timings` into 2 by

```
df['temp1'], df['temp'] = df['open_timings'].str.split('-', 1).str
```

But cant get past that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do str.split i.e

```
ndf = df['open_timings'].str.split('TO',expand=True).rename(columns={0:"start_time", 1:'closed_time' , 2:'end_time'})
af = pd.concat([df,ndf],1)
```

```
  id store_name      open_timings start_time closed_time end_time
0   1        abc   9 TO 1 -4 TO 11         9        1 -4        11
1   2        bcd  8 TO 11 - 1 TO 3         8      11 - 1         3
2   3        xyz            8 TO 2         8           2     None
3   4        qwe     9 TO 2-4 TO 7         9         2-4         7
```

To drop the columns you can do `af = af.drop(['open_timings'],1)`

`closed_time` has some ambiguity but for `start_time` and `end_time` we can use

```
for i in cols:   
    if i == 'start_time':
        hr = 0
    else:
        hr = 12
    af[i] = pd.to_datetime(af[i], format='%H')
    af[i] = af[i].apply(lambda x : np.where(pd.isnull(x),np.nan,"{}:{}".format(x.hour+hr,x.minute)))
```

```
    id store_name start_time closed_time end_time
0   1        abc        9:0       1 -4      23:0
1   2        bcd        8:0     11 - 1      15:0
2   3        xyz        8:0           2      nan
3   4        qwe        9:0        2-4      19:0
```

Comment: Nice , for converting to time format, should i use pd.to_datetime?

Comment: Without knowing `am` or `pm` how can we convert it to 24 hrs datetime. It creates ambiguity

Comment: Thats the trick, i think, consider all the start time values as AM, and end time as PM, i am unsure on Closed_time part

Comment: If you say so I upated the answer

Comment: im getting this error: `Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas` 2nd last line in the for loop